# Write formula in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have troubles with writing formula in Excel VBA.

```
Sub Macro()
  valueA1 = Range("A1").Value
  Range("C1").Formula = "=RC[-1]*" & valueA1
End Sub
```

At the end I want formula in cell C1 to be written as `=B1*0,5`, if value in B1 is `0,5`.

Thaks for the help!

Comment: and if value in "B1" is not `0.5` ? what should be the `Formula` then ? Also, do you want to **Add** or **Multiply** ? your post has `"=RC[-1]+" & valueA1` in the formula, and you say you want `=B1*0,5` at the end of your post. So, which one is it?

Comment: @ShaiRado - that's why I gave two possible answers ;)

Comment: It should be `*` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't like foreign languages.  You will need to use `FormulaR1C1Local`:

```
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1Local = "=RC[-1]+" & valueA1
```

or maybe

```
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1Local = "=RC[-1]*" & valueA1
```

if you are trying to multiply B1*A1.  (Your question says multiply, your code says add.)

That should cause it to accept `"0,5"` as a valid number.

Comment: Great! Thanks @YowE3K ! :)

Comment: My contribution to the "GOAL" :)